# How to run selenium testNG test cases using maven from command line?

Tags: maven, selenium, testng

While running my test case from maven using following command

```
c:\> mvn test
```

I am getting following result:

```
 D:\arpit_maven\mavenProject\build_demo>mvn test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building build_demo 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ build_demo
 ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\arpit_maven\mavenProject\build_dem
o\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ build_demo --
-
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ bu
ild_demo ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\arpit_maven\mavenProject\build_dem
o\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ build
_demo ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ build_demo ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: D:\arpit_maven\mavenProject\build_demo\target\
surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.031s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Mar 21 10:29:17 IST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
D:\arpit_maven\mavenProject\build_demo>
```

My POM.xml is as follows. Please let me know if anything is missing in pom.xml.
My test case is in src\test\java\ folder.

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>demo1</groupId>
<artifactId>build_demo</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>build_demo</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
 <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.33.0</version>

    </dependency>

 <dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
<groupId>org.testng</groupId>
 <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
<version>6.8.1</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.8</version>
    </dependency> 
</dependencies>
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
     <plugins>
     <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.mavan.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>mavan-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.3.2</version>
     <configuration>
     <source>1.6</source>
     <target>1.6</target>
     </configuration>
     </plugin>
     </plugins>
     </build> 
     <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>selenium-tests</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>Opencart.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
 </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Have you named the test accordingly to the surefire rules ? Like *Test.java, Test*.java etc. Apart from that you are running integration tests which should be run by maven-failsafe-plugin instead.

Comment: My testcase file name is Opencart.java. Should I change it to OpencartTest.java

Comment: Yes you have to to get it running by maven, case the naming convention of maven-surefire-plugin is the one you should follow. But as i mentioned before you are running integration tests so they should be named like OpencartIT.java and you have to configure maven-failsafe-plugin instead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename your class to OpencartTest.java OR change the filter attributes in surefire so that it picks up your Opencart.java class.  You could also create suite xml file which explicity includes Opencart.java.

Personally, I would just change the name of your class!